# python to parse json file

Tags: python, json

i am new to python and json. I have a below json file in which i need to parse the "value" from the json file

```
{
  "link": [
    {
      "attributes": [
        {
          "value": "backup",
          "name": "name"
        },
        {
          "value": "",
          "name": "description"
        }
      ],

    },
    {
      "attributes": [
        {
          "value": "com.cap.blueprints",
          "name": "name"
        },
        {
          "value": "",
          "name": "description"
        }
      ],

    }
  ],
}
```

i have tried the below code. but i am getting error

```
with open ("respose_json.txt") as f2:
 data=json.load(f2)
 for x in data:
  print(x['attributes']['value']) 

error:
    print(x['attributes']['value']) 
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Is the identation correct?

Comment: Kindly help me out . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're missing the outermost `link` key.
2. Attributes contain list of attribute and each attribute have value.

Try something like this:

```
import json

with open("respose_json.txt") as json_file:
    data = json.loads(json_file)["link"]

    for attributes in data:
        for attribute in attributes['attributes']:
            print(attribute['value'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Umair. This totally worked. Really appreciate it.